# Need to remove cupertino styles in primefaces

Tags: java, css, web, jsf, primefaces

When using the cupertino styles in primefaces, it forces me in certain sections of my page to use the default ones and doesn't let me change them, so I added the following in my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>none</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However, I would like that in some places if the styles remain and in others custom styles. Next I show the before and after.
Before(without adding the code previously written) with the cupertino styles and the respective code in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
</context-param>
```

[image]

After(wanting to add custom styles):
[image]

I would like to keep the same style of the table in the modal with cupertino, how could I achieve it?